# neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError when trying to return JSON content from Neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j

I was trying to build simple recommendation system. When I try to fetch the common products between two persons, I Get below error.

```
CypherSyntaxError: Invalid input 'p': expected whitespace, comment, ',', ORDER, SKIP, LIMIT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 180 (offset: 179))
```

My Query is in Flask and as below.

```
@app.route('/rcmd/<username>', methods=['GET'])
def rcmd(username):

session = driver.session()
result = session.run("MATCH (p:Person {name:$username})-[:PURCHASED]->(:Product)<-[:PURCHASED]-(p2:Person)-[:PURCHASED]->(pd2:Product)"
            "WHERE NOT (p)-[:PURCHASED]->(pd2)"
            "RETURN pd2.title as product_title pd2.description as product_details LIMIT 5" , username=username)
return jsonify([record[("product_title","product_details")] for record in result])
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing a comma character in the `RETURN` clause after `RETURN pd2.title as product_title`:

```
RETURN pd2.title as product_title, pd2.description as product_details
```

Comment: I did the change, Now I get this error- TypeError: ('product_title', 'product_details')